# Lambdas over polymorphic classes

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

In the code below, note that Bar derives from Foo.

```
class Program
{
    public class Foo
    {
        public string data { get; set; }
    }

    public class Bar : Foo
    {
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var bars = new List<Bar>();

        bars.Add(new Bar() { data = "hello" });
        bars.Add(new Bar() { data = "world" });

        var resultsA = GetFoos(bars, (b => b.data.StartsWith("h")));
        var resultsB = GetBars(bars, (b => b.data.StartsWith("h")));
    }

    static List<Foo> GetFoos(List<Foo> fooList, Func<Foo, bool> criteria)
    {
        return fooList.Where(criteria).ToList();
    }

    static List<Bar> GetBars(List<Bar> barList, Func<Bar, bool> criteria)
    {
        return barList.Where(criteria).ToList();
    }
}
```

The GetFoos method call results in this compiler error message:
Argument 1: cannot convert from '`System.Collections.Generic.List<Program.Bar>`' to '`System.Collections.Generic.List<Program.Foo>`'

However, when that line is commented out, the call to GetBars() executes correctly.

Is what I'm trying to accomplish here, a query against a common ancestor class, possible with linq?

Comment: Thank you, @BradleyDotNET and @RagtimeWilly; although the ease and accuracy of the answers seem to somehow disrespect how difficult I found the problem! ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Update the `List` to `IEnumerable`:

```
static IEnumerable<Foo> GetFoos(IEnumerable<Foo> fooList, Func<Foo, bool> criteria)
{
    return fooList.Where(criteria).ToList();
}

static IEnumerable<Bar> GetBars(IEnumerable<Bar> barList, Func<Bar, bool> criteria)
{
    return barList.Where(criteria).ToList();
}
```

This is because `IEnumerable<Bar>` is a subtype of `IEnumerable<Foo>`. The subtyping is preserved because `IEnumerable<T>` is covariant on `T`.

Neither `IList<Boo>` nor `IList<Foo>` is a subtype of the other, because `IList<T>` is invariant on `T`.

Comment: I'm trying to get my project back to its previously not-working earlier state; but it does appear that you're perfectly correct and the problem lies in List<T> (specifically, an errant .ToList()). Thank you!

Comment: Actually, no - I see that I also have ToList() in the code above, so that's unlikely to be the problem.

Comment: @overslacked If you are able to post some of the actual code that's causing problems I can take a look?

Comment: This was the problem. A data provider was returning an IList<>. Changed to IEnumerable<> and my filters are working. Thanks again!

Answer (score 6):

Only interfaces can be [covariant](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Since you are trying to assign a `List<Derived>` to a `List<Base>`, you need to use a covariant interface instead. `IEnumerable` is already covariant, so just change your code to:

```
static List<Foo> GetFoos(IEnumerable<Foo> fooList, Func<Foo, bool> criteria)
{
    return fooList.Where(criteria).ToList();
}

static List<Bar> GetBars(IEnumerable<Bar> barList, Func<Bar, bool> criteria)
{
    return barList.Where(criteria).ToList();
}
```

Proof on [IdeOne](https://ideone.com/1s3e4D)